# form return true not working [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

In this function, based on the value of an input, the form submit is true/false.  Why isn't return true working in this function?

```
                    <script>

                $(".askInput").keyup(function() {

                    if ($(this).val().indexOf("?") != -1) {

                        $(this).css({"color" : "#00bfff", 'border-top-right-radius' : '0px', 'border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px', '-moz-border-top-right-radius' : '0px', '-moz-border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px', '-webkit-border-top-right-radius' : '0px', '-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px'});

                        $('.searchEnter').stop().animate({
                        marginLeft: "310px"
                        }, 200 );
                        $('.form1').submit(function () {
                             return false;
                            });


                    } else {

                        $(this).css({"color" : "#333", 'border-top-right-radius' : '5px', 'border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px', '-moz-border-top-right-radius' : '5px', '-moz-border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px', '-webkit-border-top-right-radius' : '5px', '-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px'});

                        $('.searchEnter').stop().animate({
                            marginLeft: "250px"
                            }, 200 );
                        $('.form1').submit(function () {
                             return true;
                            });

                    }
                });

                </script>
```